# zoomToElement doesnt work correctly using react-zoom-pan-pinch

Tags: reactjs

Please see this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-mcnulty-b1if44)

I have an SVG canvas with 4 circles drawn on it. I also have 4 buttons that on click should zoom into the respective circles.

At the moment all buttons will only zoom to element1.

I have looked through the issues on their [Github repo](https://github.com/prc5/react-zoom-pan-pinch) but to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

What is actually happening is that the zooming factor is being restricted by       `minScale={0.4}` and `maxScale={0.7}` in the `TransformWrapper` component. The scale factor required for zooming into elements 2-4 is greater than 0.7. The maximum scale factor 0.7 makes it seem as if only `element1` is getting zoomed into.

Here's a couple of things that you could try:

1. The simplest solution is discard `maxScale` and `minScale` values in `TransformWrapper`.
2. Increase the value of `maxScale`.
3. You can also reduce the size of the circles relative to the background to reduce the zooming factor.